# Entity Framework v6 GroupBy Losing Original Ordering

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have the following part of a query (It's the end of a larger query - *queryBuilder is an IQueryable*)

```
            var results = queryBuilder
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Vehicle.RangeId)
                          .ThenBy(x => x.Rate.Rental)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.Vehicle.RangeId)
                          .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Rate.Rental);
```

It's working with an object with a Vehicle object and Rental object. There are around 12K vehicles and split into about 40 ranges (RangeId - Indexed int dictates that).

The query above works fine however is does not do what I expect. I expect for it to order the vehicles by RangeId and then by rental (Lowest rental first).

Then group them by the RangeId and select the first one from the group, which 'should' be the cheapest rental as it's ordered to be like before the groupby is called.

However. It's not. It just randomly gets one in no order. Sometimes its the second cheapest. Sometimes 5th and so on. For some reason the GroupBy is not honouring the original order!

I can get this working, by doing the following. **However** the performance is absolutely dire and takes ages to complete.

```
            var results = queryBuilder
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Vehicle.RangeId)
                          .ThenBy(x => x.Rate.Rental)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.Vehicle.RangeId)
                          .Select(x => x.OrderBy(o => o.Rate.Rental).FirstOrDefault())
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Rate.Rental);
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated. I can't firgure out why the original query is not keeping everything in order.

Comment: Try to use GroupBy first, then Order the individual groups. Should increase performance too

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the second example isn't it? The performance is dreadful on that.

Comment: I should add I have tried to remove all the order queries before the GroupBy but it makes no difference to the dreadful performance.

Comment: In the top query, I think it's the Select that's wrong. Can you try to use SelectMany(x => x.FirstOrDefault())?

Comment: I can't so SelectMany at that point. VS throws an error and won't compile.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx the orderby's aren't executed until the results are enumerated, maybe that causes the problem? Maybe if you do .AsEnumerable after the first 2 times you order, it will be resolved? (If I try your method for a similar database I don't have your problem though... it produces the results you'd expect)

Comment: I don't want to enumerate them before the group as it's paged using Skip/Take afterwards. Doing that will make the performance worse as it will have to go and get 12K+ of vehicles and rates and hold in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I expect for it to order the vehicles by RangeId and then by rental

In an LINQ to Entities query, any ordering before a `GroupBy` is simply ignored. You won't even see it in the executed SQL. That is because Entity Framework takes the grouping expression to order by (in your case `x => x.Vehicle.RangeId`). Why is that?

LINQ's `GroupBy` is seemingly similar to SQL's `GROUP BY`, but actually it's quite different.

`GROUP BY` in SQL is "destructive", by which I mean that any information other than the columns in the `GROUP BY` is lost (apart from aggregate expressions). If you do ...

```
SELECT Brand, COUNT(*) 
FROM Cars
GROUP BY Brand
```

... you only see `Brand` and their counts. You don't see the cars in the groups.

That's exactly what LINQ's `GroupBy` does: it produces groups of *complete* objects. All information in the original data is still there. You'll see cars grouped by their brands.

That means that ORMs that translate `GroupBy` as `GROUP BY` give themselves a hard time building the result set. LINQ to SQL does that. It executes a `GROUP BY` query first and then it needs separate queries (one per group actually) to make up for the "lost" data.

EF implements `GroupBy` differently. It gets all data in one query and then it builds the groups in memory. You won't see `GROUP BY` in the generated SQL. You see an `ORDER BY` instead. I think EF prefers a sorted SQL query result for more efficient processing in memory. (And I can imagine combines better with other LINQ statements in the pipeline).

So that's why any ordering before `GroupBy` is ignored. And why you can only apply ordering after the grouping.

> the performance is absolutely dire

It's hard to tell from here why that is. Maybe you can do the ordering in memory:

```
var results = queryBuilder
              .GroupBy(x => x.Vehicle.RangeId)
              .Select(x => x.OrderBy(o => o.Rate.Rental).FirstOrDefault())
              .Select(o => new { o.Rate.Rental, o }
              .AsEnumerable()
              .OrderBy(x => x.Rental);
```

But it may also be an indexing issue. If there's no proper index on `Rate.Rental`, ordering by that column is expensive.

Comment: Absolutely amazing reply thanks. Appreciate your time to explain it.